# Compile expansion mystery of macro in Elisp

Tags: macros, elisp

I always have confusion about `macro` in Emacs. There has been many documents about how to use `macro`. But the documents only mention the surface and examples are often too simple. In addition, it is quite hard to search `macro` itself. It will come up with keyboard macro results.

People always say macro is expanded at compile time and it is as fast as writing the same copy of code directly. Is this always true?

I start with the example `when`.

```
(pp-macroexpand-expression
 '(when t
    (print "t")))

;; (if t
;;     (progn
;;       (print "t")))
```

When we use `when` during compiling, the `(if t .....)` is inserted to our code directly, right?

Then, I find a more complicated example `dotimes` from `subr.el`. I simplified the code a bit:

```
(defmacro dotimes (spec &rest body)

  (declare (indent 1) (debug dolist))

  (let ((temp '--dotimes-limit--)
        (start 0)
        (end (nth 1 spec)))

    `(let ((,temp ,end)
           (,(car spec) ,start))
       (while (< ,(car spec) ,temp)
         ,@body
         (setq ,(car spec) (1+ ,(car spec))))
       ,@(cdr (cdr spec)))))
```

What drew my attention is the `(end (nth 1 spec))`. I think this part must be done at runtime. When this is done at runtime, it implies that the code expansion cannot be done at compile time.
To test with it, I modified the `dotimes` a bit and byte-compile the file.

```
(defmacro my-dotimes (spec &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1) (debug dolist))
  (let ((temp '--dotimes-limit--)
        (start 0)
        ;; This is my test
        (end (and (print "test: ")(print (nth 1 spec)) (nth 1 spec))))
    `(let ((,temp ,end)
           (,(car spec) ,start))
       (while (< ,(car spec) ,temp)
         ,@body
         (setq ,(car spec) (1+ ,(car spec))))
       ,@(cdr (cdr spec)))))

(provide 'my)
```

Result

```
(require 'my)
(my-dotimes (var 3)
  (print "dotimes"))

;; "test: "
;; 3
;; "dotimes"
;; "dotimes"
;; "dotimes"
```

Indeed, my test statement is done at runtime.
When it comes to expansion:

```
(pp-macroexpand-expression
 '(my-dotimes (var 3)
    (print "dotimes")))

;; (let
;;     ((--dotimes-limit-- 3)
;;      (var 0))
;;   (while
;;       (< var --dotimes-limit--)
;;     (print "dotimes")
;;     (setq var
;;           (1+ var))))
```

Surprisingly my test part lost.

So is `dotimes` expanded at runtime?

If yes, does it mean it losses the advantage of a generic `macro` that `macro` is as fast as writing the same code directly?

What does the interpreter do when it meets `macro` that have runtime components and?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the impression that you byte-compiled the file containing the macro *definition*, but did not byte-compile the file which calls the macro?

It is the *calls* to a macro which get expanded.

Expansion happens at compile-time if the calling code is compiled; at load-time ("eager" macro expansion, only in recent Emacs versions) if the loaded code is not compiled; and at run-time if eager expansion was not possible or not available.

Obviously if a call to a macro is evaluated at run-time, there was never any opportunity to expand it in advance, so expansion happens right away, at run-time.

Macro expansion at compile time (or load time) is possible because macro arguments are *not* evaluated. There is nothing problematic about `(nth 1 spec)` being evaluated at expansion time, because the value of `spec` is the *unevaluated* argument which appeared in the original call to the macro.

i.e. When expanding `(dotimes (var 3))` the `spec` argument is the list `(var 3)` and `(nth 1 spec)` is therefore evaluated at expansion-time to `3`.

For clarity (as numbers could confuse matters here), if it had been `(nth 0 spec)` then it would have evaluated to the symbol `var`, and in particular **not** `var`'s *value as a variable* (which cannot be established at expansion time).

So `(nth 1 spec)` -- and indeed any manipulation of the unevaluated arguments passed to the macro -- can *absolutely* be established at expansion time.

(edit: Wait, we covered this in [Can I put condition in emacs lisp macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973029/can-i-put-condition-in-emacs-lisp-macro) )

If you are asking what happens if the macro does something at expansion-time with a value that is *dynamic at run-time*, the answer is simply that it sees the expansion-time value, and consequently the expanded code might vary depending on when the expansion occurred. There's nothing preventing you from writing macros which behave this way, but it's generally not advisable.

Comment: Finally, I got everything right. I have long been confusing because I never byte-compiled a file which use the macro. I just byte-compiled the macro file itself. And if anyone byte-compiled a file, macro MUST be expanded. This is the two points I have problem with before. You may not know how much I was grateful to your answer..

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents...

> People always say macro is expanded at compile time and it is as fast as writing the same copy of code directly. Is this always true?

It's not exactly always true.

If you compile a function whose code contains a call to a macro, it's true.

But, if you don't compile it, it's almost true.

Suppose you define a function using your modified version of `dotimes`, like:

```
(defun foo (x)
  (my-dotimes (var x)
    (print "dotimes")))
```

and you *don't* compile it.

If you call only once `(foo 5)`, the interpreter will have to expand the macro before evaluating the expanded code, so you will see the prints and it will be slower than if you had written yourself the expanded code inside the function.

But now, the symbol `my-times` does not appear anymore in the definition of `foo`. The list that contained it has been replaced by the result of its expansion.

So, if you call again `foo`, like `(foo 3)`, now you don't see anymore the prints and it will be as fast as if you had written yourself the expanded code.